# Want to extend XML Web part, what is the easiest way when the existing Web-part is sealed class?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I need to extend XML Web-part to allow some custom properties. What is the easiest way as the existing XML Web-Part class is sealed?

The extended custom properties will be used to derive attributes of the XML Web-part like XML Url, XSL Url etc.

-Gandalf

Answer (score 1):

Since it’s a simple webpart, I think the easiest way would be to write it yourself. You can always take a peak on Microsoft’s code using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: Ya, in fact I have taken the same approach, but I though thr might be better approach. In this case my requirement is pretty straight, but what in case of the requirement is such that developing it from scratch is not possible, or is it a standard (to re-invent the wheel) when it comes to SharePoint development?